# Using boundaries to HTTP Post multiple data

Tags: ios, swift, http-post, nsurlsession

In my iOS Application, I am trying to post data to a server with HTTP Post request. I am using the following method to create the request body;

```
func createBodyWithParameters(filePathKey: String?, boundary: String) -> NSData {
    let body = NSMutableData()
    let filename = String(format: "%lld.jpg", NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970 * 1000)
    let data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.photoTaken , 0.6)
    println(data.length)
    let mimetype = "image/png"

    body.appendString("--\(boundary)\r\n")
    body.appendString("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(filePathKey!)\"; filename=\"\(filename)\"\r\n")
    //body.appendString("Category: \(self.categoryAbbreviations[self.tag])\r\n")
    body.appendString("Content-Type: \(mimetype)\r\n\r\n")
    body.appendData(data!)
    body.appendString("\r\n")

    body.appendString("--\(boundary)--\r\n")
    body.appendString("Category: \(self.categoryAbbreviations[self.tag])\r\n")
    body.appendString("--\(boundary)--\r\n")
    return body
}
```

I am separating the category information and image data with boundaries. However, the server responds to this with HTTP error 400 (Bad Request). If I try to send the category information and image data together, I receive HTTP error 413 (Request Entity Too Large)

I think the problem is that I am creating my request body wrong. Is there any problem with the request data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two issues

1. You're terminating the body too soon. The `--boundary--` syntax is for the end of the body.
2. You are not properly encoding the `Category` value.

So, it should probably look something like:

```
// add category

body.appendString("--\(boundary)\r\n")
body.appendString("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"Category\"\r\n\r\n")
body.appendString("\(self.categoryAbbreviations[self.tag])\r\n")

// now all done 

body.appendString("--\(boundary)--\r\n")
```

Frankly, one might consider using AFNetworking to create these multipart requests, as it simplifies the process.

---

References:

- [HTML 4.0 Specification, Section 17.13.4](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.2)
- [RFC 2388](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2388.txt)

Comment: I had the feeling that AFNetworking could be better. Now I will try it it for sure! For now, I have replaced my code with yours and it is working fine. Thank you!